# VMWare Gateway on a different network

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vmware

I'm new into networking. My home network is normally 192.168.2.0/24 and .1 is my gateway.
So I'm trying to build my small lab in vmware. I want my vm ubuntu machine to have a 10.10.10.6 address.

It is using Bridged (Automatic) network adapter, and network adapter is configured to use my wifi adapter (I'm on a laptop).
This is my netplan configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.10.10.6/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4]
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.2.1
        on-link: true
```

I cannot ping the gateway or any device on my network... When I change the ip address to something in 192.168.2.0 network, I can ping the gateway or devices on my network and get out.

What am I missing? I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A bridged network adapter means that it is going to try to use the existing network which is 192.168.2.0/24.  10.10.10.6 is outside the range that your network uses so it doesn't work as it supports 192.168.2.2-254

You would have to use a NAT network to give the system its own private network to work from if you want to stick with 10.10.10.1/24, though you may have restrictions communicating between the 192.168.2.0/24 and the 10.10.10.1/24 network.

Comment: And a private NAT network will need your gateway IP address in the range.  VMware builds a default NAT network by default, you may want to use that instead.